# Hover Image Not Showing...?

Tags: css, image

I'm having trouble with a toolbar for my website... I'm doing pretty well with it but some parts of it aren't working too well. I'm trying to make it so that the image changes color/image on hover. However that doesn't seem to be working when I use the background-image tag in css. It shows the original image that I had but doesn't change... Here's what I have so far

```
#heading-button-1{
margin-left: 15%;
background-image: url(toolbar-button-home-default.png);
display: block; 
}

#heading-button-1:hover{
background-image: url(Website/toolbar-button-tracks-highlighted.png);   
width: 7%;
height: 8%;
display: block;
}

    <a type="button" id="heading-button-1" title="Home" href="#" target="_blank" class="toolbar-buttons">
    </a>

    <a title="Tracks" href="#" target="_blank" class="toolbar-buttons">
    <img type="button" id="heading-button-2" src="Website/toolbar-button-tracks-default.png" width"7%" class="toolbar-buttons"/>
    </a>
```

But that doesn't seem to be working as you can see in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPxLX.png) I took. I'm using Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2015 so if you have any links, suggestions or solutions, please help :)

Comment: Does `img` tag support the `type` attribute?

Comment: Pretty sure yeah, I saw someone do it on a site

Comment: Are you having trouble with a second link not appearing, or a background hover effect not appearing?

Comment: It half worked when I changed to the background image but it's not changing on hover

Answer (score 0):

You can do this solely with javascript and images if you want.

**Using onmouseover and onmouseout**

```
<a title="Tracks" href="#" target="_blank" class="toolbar-buttons">
<img src="Original.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='Hover.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='Original.jpg'" border="0" alt=""/>
</a>
```

You'd just replace `Original.jpg` with the link to your original image, and replace `Hover.jpg` with the image you want to replace it with upon hover.

**Using onclick**

You can also use `onclick` to change the image when clicked but this is not recommended for navigation links since there is a chance that when the link is clicked that the new page will be loaded before the user has a chance to see the replaced image.

```
<a title="Tracks" href="#" target="_blank" class="toolbar-buttons">
<img src="Original.jpg" onclick="this.src='Click.jpg'" border="0" alt=""/>
</a>
```

Comment: Hah thanks for that, I heard you could do an onmouseover command but I hadn't seen anything online about it

Comment: No problem. I don't think many people use it anymore, but I've used it in the past for social media icons, swapping a grayscale one for a full color one. Happy coding. :)

Comment: Yeah, you know when you click it change to a darker/lighter image or something

Comment: I updated my answer with an example for `onclick` as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the link for the hover image, I don't think it's correct. Especially if your server running Linux it's case sensitive, so `url(Website/...` and `url(website/...` is two different addresses.
2. Why are you changing height and width of the buttons on hover? Is it suppose to be that way?
3. I believe you can set `display: block;` only once, in the non-hover styles and it should be enough.
4. You also may want to get rid of this tiny blue dash between buttons - `text-decoration: none;` will do the job
5. If your .png files that you use as a background images contain only one color it's a lot simpler to use `background-color: #CC393E;`. And it will speed up page loading

```css
nav a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #CC393E;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: #af2c30;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Tracks</a>
</nav>
```

It's a really simple thing you're asking about, there's no need to use javascript